# Alfresco custom action permission

Tags: permissions, action, alfresco

I have done a custom action. I can see the action  in documentary library but  i canot see it on faceted search result page.

```
 <action id="custom-action" type="javascript"  label="actions.custom.action">
        <param name="function">onCustomActionlick</param>
     </action>
```

So I went in  the `aikau-1.0.8.1.jar\META-INF\js\aikau\1.0.8.1\alfresco\renderers\_ActionsMixin.js` file.

I see that  we do a test to determine if action is allowed in this file :

```
if (this.filterActions === false || AlfArray.arrayContains(this.allowedActions, action.id))
```

On firebug i see that my costum action is not in the `allowedActions` object. My question is why ?

I think that actions wich have not permission are always allowed to all users.  Am I right ?

What can i do to allow this action et make it visible on  faceted search result page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write an extension module which is described here: https://forums.alfresco.com/comment/159331#comment-159331.

In the JavaScript code you need to get the widget id of **MERGED_ACTIONS** and add your customAction to the array of allowdActions and define it in CustomActions.

This is the Aikau code from the link, probably it has been updated in the newer Alfresco version. So you need to extend this within your extension module.
You can probably just use **org\alfresco\share\pages\faceted-search** as your `<sourcePackageRoot>` in the module.

```
widgets: [{
    id: "MERGED_ACTIONS",
    name: "alfresco/renderers/Actions",
    config: {
        filterActions: true,
        mergeActions: true,
        allowedActions: ["folder-manage-rules", "folder-download", "folder-view-details", "CUSTOM3"],
        customActions: [{
            id: "CUSTOM3",
            label: "Custom Action 3",
            icon: "document-delete",
            index: "10",
            publishTopic: "DELETE_ACTION_TOPIC",
            type: "javascript"
        }],
        widgetsForActions: [{
            name: "alfresco/renderers/actions/ManageAspects"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you help me to add custom action in search resule aikau page?

Answer (score 3):

The Document Library (at least up until Alfresco Share 5.1) is built with YUI, whereas the search page is built using Aikau. At the time of writing there is not yet parity of action handling between the search page and the Document Library, and the process of adding actions is very different.

In order to get your custom action to display in the faceted search page you'll need to do a couple of things:

- Extend the search page to update the configuration for the "alfresco/search/AlfSearchResult" (it has the id "FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT") to add your custom actions to the "additionalDocumentAndFolderActions" array (see http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfSearchResult.html)
- Your custom action will publish a topic, so you need to create a new service to subscribe to that topic to perform the action. You will need to further extend the faceted search page so that your service is included on the page.

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750810/alfresco-aikau-custom-action but not able to see custom action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm paraphrasing from our [latest blog](https://www.parashift.com.au/2016/06/28/adding-custom-action-shares-faceted-search/) the method we've used for this.

Our use case was we had existing actions in the document library view we didn't want to have to recreate, with standard configuration xml.

The first step is to create a Share Extension Module to add a Javascript controller in `web-extensions/site-data/extensions/example.xml`:

```
<extension>
  <modules>
        <module>
            <id>Example Service</id>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
            <customizations>
                <customization>
                    <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.share.pages.faceted-search</targetPackageRoot>
                    <sourcePackageRoot>com.parashift.example</sourcePackageRoot>
                </customization>
            </customizations>
        </module>
    </modules>
</extension>
```

This will load some extra javascript, allowing you to adjust the widget config.

Create a file in `web-extension/site-webscripts/com/parashift/example/faceted-search.get.js` (or whatever package name you've used in `sourcePackageRoot`), add in a file called `faceted-search.get.js` with the following contents:

```
var searchResultPage = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel.widgets, "id", "FCTSRCH_SEARCH_RESULT");

if(searchResultPage != null) {
    searchResultPage.config = {
        enableContextMenu : false,
        mergeActions : true,
        additionalDocumentAndFolderActions : ["example-action"]
    }
}

model.jsonModel.widgets.push({
    id: "EXAMPLE_LISTENER",
    name: "parashift/action/example"
});
```

This will:

- Add `example-action` to the list of actions in the search results.  This should already be a configured action in some share-config.xml file.
- Add a new listener widget for you to listen to when the action button is clicked.

Add a file for your listener widget: `META-INF/parashift/action/example.js`

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "alfresco/core/Core"
    ],
    function(declare, _Widget, Core) {
        return declare([_Widget, Core], {

            postCreate: function () {
                this.alfSubscribe("ALF_SINGLE_DOCUMENT_ACTION_REQUEST", lang.hitch(this, this._onPayloadReceive));
            },

            _onPayloadReceive: function (payload) {

                if(payload.action.id == "example-action") {
                        this.alfLog("log", "Received action, handling accordingly");
                        ....... 
                }
            }

        });
});
```

This code will listen for `ALF_SINGLE_DOCUMENT_ACTION_REQUEST` and execute the `_onPayloadReceive` function.  In this function we filter to the `example-action` and execute any custom code.

The `payload` variable will include `document` and `action` objects.  Using Debug Logging you can see what their shape is.

This is roughly equivalent to the old YUI method:

```
YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("registerAction", {
    actionName: "onExampleAction",
    fn: function(file) {
      console.log("Received action, handling accordingly");
      ....
    }
});
```

Comment: You're example is missing "dojo/_base/lang" dependency

Comment: Can you help me to add custom action ? I tried above code but not working.